# How to check if NET assembly was already added in Matlab?

Tags: .net, matlab

Using matlab 2010 with NET.addAssembly(MyName), how do I check whether certain assembly MyName was already added or not?

Comment: Not sure but you could try `exist()` http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/exist.html It works for Java classes, so I hope it would also work for .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `isempty(which(MyName))` - I believe that if MyName is not defined/loaded then this will be empty (i.e., true), otherwise not (false).

Comment: I've tried this in multiple versions ('MyName', 'MyName.dll', 'c:\Full\MyName.dll') but it doesn't work. Even after I'm loading the .net assembly I still get empty (true) value.

Comment: This method works for me if I test for a something that exists in the assembly (structures, classes, methods etc). For example `isempty(which('MyCompany.MyProduct.MyClass'))`

Answer (score 4):

I've found a code 
[which checks for added assembly.](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/matlab/134956/NET-addAssembly-warnings)
Maybe I can alter it to something like

```
function flag = IsAssemblyAdded( MyName )

domain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
assemblies = domain.GetAssemblies;
flag = false;

for i= 1:assemblies.Length

    asm = assemblies.Get(i-1);    
    disp(char(asm.FullName));
    if strcmpi(asm.FullName, MyName)
        flag = true;
    end

end
```

for checking whether the assembly is loaded to matlab or not.

[edited]

Answer (score 2):

The following works in R2013a and looks for the assembly short name:

```
function loaded = IsAssemblyAdded( MyName )

assembiles = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies;
loaded = false;
i = 0;
while (i < assembiles.Length && ~loaded)
    loaded = strcmp(char(assembiles.Get(i).GetName.Name), MyName);
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Comment: This will only work if the assembly being tested is the last one. Otherwise `loaded` will become `false` again. You should have an `if loaded; break; end` statement within your while

Answer (score 0):

Straight strcmp may not work (at least as of 2011b) as the FullName method will return a much longer string. E.g:

`"mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`

Something like this might work better:

`regexp(char(asm.FullName),['^', MyName, ','],'once')`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
asm = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies;
any(arrayfun(@(n) strncmpi(char(asm.Get(n-1).FullName), MyName, length(MyName)), 1:asm.Length))
```